Did US take their most prolific basketball players to the 2004 Summer Olympics?
In my country, they are talking about how 20 years ago Argentina defeated the USA basketball "Dream Team" in the  2004 Summer Olympics.
Now, if I recall correctly, even if it still was nicknamed "Dream Team", US didn't take his best players to this tournament. I know for example Lebron James was there, but he was very young and only played 3 minutes.
I was wondering if US took their most prolific players to this tournament; I don't know all the metrics in basketball, but the ones I see the most in match stats are points, assists and rebounds. Considering these metrics, and their last season to the Olympics, did US take their most prolific basketball players to the  2004 Summer Olympics?

The simple answer here is "no, they did not take their best players". While you could probably get a similar answer from looking at your suggested metrics, two much quicker to determine facts about the 2004 roster:

Of the 12 players who easily won the last major tournament the USA competed in, the 2003 Tournament of the Americas, only 3 of them went to the Olympics. Yes, you may expect some roster turnover in a year but not that much.
One of the highest allocades in the NBA is the All-NBA Team; only one player (Tim Duncan) from that year's All-NBA team went to the Olympics despite 12 out of the 15 players on the All-NBA Team being American.


May be worth noting that according to Wikipedia, the nine players from the Tournament of the Americas squad who didn't make the Olympics squad ruled themselves out of contention (mostly due to injuries) rather than simply not being picked.

@F1Krazy I'd have to dig into the details (which by now may be vanished into the aether) but I suspect a lot of those "injuries" were "wear and tear from the NBA season" which can also be phrased as "I don't want to risk my very, very lucrative NBA career if I pick up an injury at the Olympics" (which is a fair position for individuals to take).
